# JMeter load test causes target server to reach 100% CPU

Tags: jmeter

I've been tasked with delivering a report of server performance on a client's QA server. Client ideally wants to load test with ~900 concurrent users since that is their usual amount in peak times. However, the load tests I've been doing are putting their QA server quickly up to 100% CPU with only 50 concurrent users and eventually it just freezes and becomes unusable, so right now they just want to know if it's their QA server that is the problem (low CPU / RAM) or if I am taking the wrong steps.

I am using JMeter on a remote server, hitting the QA server (which is in its network). I am running it in console mode without listeners. The QA servers have a quad core CPU running at 2.50 gHz, 4 GB RAM. Production server, and the server I'm running JMeter on are the same.

I saw a [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261570/cpu-utilization-reaches-100-when-i-perform-execution-with-jmeter-in-distributed) saying that high CPU can be because of high memory in the JVM. So I looked for things to monitor JVM memory usage and came across VisualVM. Unfortunately I don't understand it well enough to use it; I have it installed on the QA server but I can't figure out a way to have it find the test plan that is running on the other server. I start it right after starting the test plan, but nothing shows up. I did add the remote server but I don't see any option to go from there.

Is there another load generation utility I should be using or any alternate steps to take?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations on finding the bottleneck. If target server is not able to handle 100 users you should determine the maximum number of users it can support by:

1. Increasing the load **gradually**, i.e. use change ramp-up time so extra user will be added each several seconds.
2. At the same time inspect the target server CPU usage via i.e. [PerfMon](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/)  JMeter Plugin
3. When CPU usage of the target server will get close to 100% - mention how many users were hitting the server at that time using i.e. [Active Threads Over Time Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)
4. Going forward it is a good practice to get to the bottom of the issue and check which process caused high CPU usage and depending on the outcome you can suggest either move the process to another server (in case if it is i.e. database server) or [do some profiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_(computer_programming)) if the problem is with the application under test to identify which component is that CPU intensive

See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for detailed PerfMon plugin configuration and usage instructions.

Comment: I updated my ramp up time to 2 minutes which seemed to help a little bit. What's weird is that the QA box doesn't immediately go up to 100% when I have 50 users running. It takes about 2-3 minutes. For a few minutes it will be somewhere between 5-30% CPU. Then it just skyrockets for some reason, but the number of threads listed in resmon don't change (they were 95 before it went to 100% and during): https://i.imgur.com/BZXxCh0.png

Comment: Also I was going to install the Perfmon JMeter plugin but it seems my JMeter version doesn't support plugins - no Plugin Manager in the Options tab.

Comment: This is because Plugin Manager is the plugin itself as well and it needs to be installed %). Check out [How to Install the JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) guide for detailed instructions

Comment: I downloaded the plugin manager .jar and put it in the lib folder, restarted JMeter, still no Plugin Manager option.

Comment: You need to drop it to **lib/ext** folder, not lib.

Comment: Aha. Ok, I got that to work. What could be the cause of a website getting 50 concurrent users but not maxing out on CPU until 2 minutes later? It's very strange because the user count isn't changing during those two minutes and nothing else is going on in the server.

Comment: Sounds like a classic memory leak, i.e. something like not freeing up unused memory, unclosed handle or thread in your application. That's why you should not limit your testing to simulating anticipated number of users only. More details: [Why ‘Normal’ Load Testing Isn’t Enough](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-%E2%80%98normal%E2%80%99-load-testing-isn%E2%80%99t-enough)

Comment: Thanks for all your advice.